# Remove elements from String array using another String array Java

Tags: java, arrays

I am trying to remove elements from String A using an array of String B.
My logic is to convert the string A to an array and then check if A contains the same elements as B and write that data to an empty String, but it doesn't work if B has two or more elements.
Can you tell me what I'm doing wrong?

```
class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        WordDeleter wordDeleter = new WordDeleter();

        // Hello
        System.out.println(wordDeleter.remove("Hello Java", new String[] { "Java" }));

        // The Athens in
        System.out.println(wordDeleter.remove("The Athens is in Greece", new String[] { "is", "Greece" }));

        // This cat
        System.out.println(wordDeleter.remove("This is cat", new String[] { "is" }));
    }
}

class WordDeleter {
    public String remove(String phrase, String[] words) {       
        String[] arrayPhrase = phrase.split(" ");       
        String result = "";
        
        for (int i = 0; i < arrayPhrase.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < words.length; j++) {
                if (!arrayPhrase[i].equalsIgnoreCase(words[j]))
                    result += arrayPhrase[i] + " ";
            }
        }
        return result.trim();
    }
}
```

Output is:

```
Hello
The The Athens Athens is in in Greece
This cat
```

Comment: When you say remove elements, you mean that `if(certainWord in stringA and certainWord in stringB), remove from stringB?`

Comment: This means I need to collect the data from Sting A without the words from String B, hope you understand @BenjaminW.

Comment: The result should be \\Hello, \\The Athens in, \\This cat 
@BenjaminW.

Comment: Mind that arrays have **no behavior** in Java, it's impossible to invoke `contains()` or any other method on the array instance. `words.contains()` would not even compile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most efficient way to remove all occurrences of strings contained in the given *array* from the *given string* is to generate a `HashSet` from the given *array* and check for every word in the *given string*, whether it's present in the *set* or not.

To avoid overheads of string concatenation, we can use `StringJoiner`.

That's how it can be implemented.

```
public static String remove(String phrase, String[] words) {
    String[] arrayPhrase = phrase.split(" ");
    Set<String> wordsToRemove = Arrays.stream(words).collect(Collectors.toSet());
    StringJoiner result = new StringJoiner(" ");
    
    for (String word: arrayPhrase) {
        if (!wordsToRemove.contains(word)) {
            result.add(word);
        }
    }
    
    return result.toString();
}
```

And that's how it can be implemented with streams using collector `joining()`:

```
public static String remove(String phrase, String[] words) {
    
    Set<String> wordsToRemove = Arrays.stream(words).collect(Collectors.toSet());
    
    return Arrays.stream(phrase.split(" "))
        .filter(word -> !wordsToRemove.contains(word))
        .collect(Collectors.joining(" "));
}
```

[*A link to Online Demo*](https://www.jdoodle.com/ia/tnh)

Answer (score 2):

You're close but you need to use the helpful `.contains()` method. This should work for the multi-length set of words. Your nested `for loop` checked for both words, thus the copying. Also the not-allowed words were only written once, so it infact "worked" but not the way you intended.

```
class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        WordDeleter wordDeleter = new WordDeleter();

        // Hello
        System.out.println(wordDeleter.remove("Hello Java", new String[] { "Java" }));

        // The Athens in
        System.out.println(wordDeleter.remove("The Athens is in Greece", new String[] { "is", "Greece" }));

        // This cat
        System.out.println(wordDeleter.remove("This is cat", new String[] { "is" }));
    }
}

class WordDeleter {
    public String remove(String phrase, String[] wordsArray) {       
        List<String> words = Arrays.asList(wordsArray);
        String[] arrayPhrase = phrase.split(" ");       
        String result = "";
        
        for (int i = 0; i < arrayPhrase.length; i++) {
            // If the word is not contained in the not allowed array
            if(!words.contains(arrayPhrase[i])){
                       result += arrayPhrase[i] + " ";
            }
        }
        return result.trim();
    }
}
```

Another thing you can do to make it better is use `StringBuilder`.
Instead of `String result = ""`, use `StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder()`. And instead of `result +=arrayPhrase[i] + " ";` use `result.append(arrayPhrase[i] + " ");` as so:

```
class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        WordDeleter wordDeleter = new WordDeleter();

        // Hello
        System.out.println(wordDeleter.remove("Hello Java", new String[] { "Java" }));

        // The Athens in
        System.out.println(wordDeleter.remove("The Athens is in Greece", new String[] { "is", "Greece" }));

        // This cat
        System.out.println(wordDeleter.remove("This is cat", new String[] { "is" }));
    }
}

class WordDeleter {
    public String remove(String phrase, String[] words) {       
        String[] arrayPhrase = phrase.split(" ");       
        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
        
        for (int i = 0; i < arrayPhrase.length; i++) {
            // If the word is not contained in the not allowed array
            if(!words.contains(arrayPhrase[i])){
                      result.append(arrayPhrase[i] + " ");
            }
        }
        return result.toString().trim();
    }
}
```